# How to save data without ngModel in template driven approach

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5

I am stuck in a situation where I have to save data to the database from Angular UI. I am showing a tabular format data where the table data **(table header and table value)** changes based on some dropdown selection.

Without having a model where properties are defined to which the data will be bind to, how can one save the data to the database?

I thought of creating a model class and keeping all the properties into it so that whenever on the dropdown selection, when we fetch data from the database, I can select the data and bind it to those properties. But that information is in hundred. Creating 100+ properties would be okay? When we dont know how many values will be displayed in the UI.

For example the dropdown has 4 values A, B, C, D. On the selection of A, 15 rows(including the table header and data) are returned, On selection of B, 30. On selection of C, 50, etc..

These values are then displayed in the tabular format. **(i.e. 15, 30, 50.. columns,)**

For displaying, I am using the following code:

**.ts**

```
async ngOnInit() {
    try {
        this.equipmentTypeInfo = await this.parameterService.getEquipmentTypes().toPromise();
        this.onEquipmentTypeSelectionChange(this.equipmentTypeInfo.length > 0 ? this.equipmentTypeInfo[0] : undefined);

    } catch (error) {
        this.errorService.handlePageError(error);
    }
}    

async onEquipmentTypeSelectionChange(equipment: any) {
    if (this.demoheader.length > 0)
        this.demoheader = [];
    this.solverData = new Map<string, string>();
    //this.clearComponentVariables();
    try {
        if (equipment) {
            this.selectedEquipmentType = equipment;
        }
        this.searchModel.templateUrn = equipment;
        this.searchModel.maxRows = 76;
        this.isLoading = true;
        //this.errorComponent.clearError();
        this.parameterModels = await this.parameterService.getEquipmentTypeSearchResults(equipment).toPromise();


        const groups = this.parameterModels.reduce((groups, param) => {
            groups[param.entityName] = groups[param.entityName] || [];
            groups[param.entityName].push(param);
            return groups;
        }, {});

        //Adding in the Dictionary format
        const groupArrays = Object.keys(groups).map((entityName) => {
            return {
                entityName,
                solverParameterData: groups[entityName]
            };
        });
        for (var i = 0; i < groupArrays.length; ++i) {
            this.solverData.set("Equipment Name", groupArrays[i].entityName);
            groupArrays[i].solverParameterData.forEach(y => {
            //since the column would be same for the data, therefore, getting the first set and then breaking.
                this.solverData.set(y.attributeUrn, y.value);
            });
            break;
        }

        this.groupDataInfo = groupArrays;
        this.solverData.forEach((item, key) => {
            this.demoheader.push(key);
            this.demoValue.push(item);
        });

    } catch (error) {
        this.errorService.handlePageError(error);
    } finally {
        this.isLoading = false;
    }
}
```

**.html**

```
<table class="tableInfo">
    <thead *ngIf="parameterModels?.length > 0">
        <tr>
            <th class="tableheaders" *ngFor="let paramType of demoheader; let i = index">
                {{paramType}}
            </th>               
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let paramTypes of groupDataInfo; let i = index">
            <td>
                <div class="tabledataEquipmentNameInfo">
                    <input id="entityName" type="text" name="{{paramTypes.entityName}}{{i}}" value="{{paramTypes.entityName}}" class="form-control" disabled>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td *ngFor="let paramType of paramTypes.solverParameterData; let ii = index">
                <div class="tabledataEquipmentNameInfo">
                    <input id="entityName" type="text" name="{{paramTypes.entityName}}{{i}}" value="{{paramType.value}}" class="form-control" disabled>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>

</table>
```

I am able to show the data. But the question now arises, How will I save the data. I have not created any model. Also, there can be more than 1 rows and I can edit any row information. We do have dirty property but that would also work on model. Any way to achieve the save. or I have to create a model class and then use the ngmodel?

Comment: Why are you duplicating name and id attributes?

Answer (score 0):

The easy way would be either to use ReactiveForms or just have data model - an array of row models, but since you want to do it the hard way....

You can wrap everything into a `<form>` and do plain old HTML form submission.

```
<form action="some/backend/path" method="POST">
   Here goes yours table with inputs - just use correct `name` attribute as now you are duplicatiing them

<button type="submit">DO IT</button>
</form>
```

if you need to so something about that form/data prior submission, you can always hook into `onsubmit` form.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Even in Reactive Form, you have to create formgroup with formControls right. here I dont know how many controls I will get!! any thought in how to achieve via ReactiveForms? I am open to both.

Comment: Does not matter, you create groups/arrays in loop. It can be fully dynamic and gives you validation/hooks/io operations for free. Firs hit on google happens to be an angular docs reference https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-form#compose-form-groups

Comment: Can you point me to any supporting article for this? I will be more than happy to use it

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-form#compose-form-groups